# Highcharts Spiderweb with different max values

Tags: highcharts

I nead to create graph Highcharts Spiderweb. Is it possible to set different max values for each category?

[image: Illustration]

At the moment all points are settled in one coordinate system. But there are uncoupled values.

Answer (score 0):

In the spiderweb you can have only one yAxis.